# How to use tabulate function to count zeros?

Tags: r

I am trying to count integers in a vector that also contains zeros. However, tabulate doesn't count the zeros.  Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Example:

```
> tabulate(c(0,4,4,5))
[1] 0 0 0 2 1
```

but the answer I expect is:

```
[1] 1 0 0 0 2 1
```

Comment: Similar to Maurits Evers' answer, you can just add `abs(min(x)) + 1` to ensure that all the elements are positive. `x <- -10:10; tabulate(x + abs(min(x)) + 1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `factor` and define its levels

```
tabulate(factor(c(0,4,4,5), 0:5))
#[1] 1 0 0 0 2 1
```

The explanation for the behaviour you're seeing is in `?tabulate` (bold face mine)

> bin: a numeric vector (**of positive integers**), or a factor.  Long
>             vectors are supported.

In other words, if you give a `numeric` vector, it needs to have positive `>0` integers. Or use a `factor`.

Comment: Note that the `factor` workaround works only if you have the _maximal_ value present in your input vector. For instance, `tabulate(factor(c(0,4,4,5), 0:6))` also returns `# [1] 1 0 0 0 2 1`, i.e. the zero count for `6` is **not** included.

Answer (score 0):

I got annoyed enough by `tabulate` to write a short function that can count not only the zeroes but any other integers in a vector:

```
my.tab <- function(x, levs) {
  sapply(levs, function(n) {
    length(x[x==n])
  }
)}
```

The parameter `x` is an integer vector that we want to tabulate. `levs` is another integer vector that contains the "levels" whose occurrences we count. Let's set `x` to some integer vector:

```
x <- c(0,0,1,1,1,2,4,5,5)
```

A) Use `my.tab` to emulate R's built-in `tabulate`. 0-s will be ignored:

```
my.tab(x, 1:max(x))
# [1] 3 1 0 1 2
```

B) Count the occurrences of integers from 0 to 6:

```
my.tab(x, 0:6)
# [1] 2 3 1 0 1 2 0
```

C) If you want to know (for some strange reason) only how many 1-s and 4-s your `x` vector contains, but ignore everything else:

```
my.tab(x, c(1,4))
# [1] 3 1
```